# Mathematica 12 not compatible with Mac OS 11 (Big Sur)? Just updated to 12 for OS 10.15 (Catalina) compatibility

Tags: mac-os-x

I just got an email from Wolfram, pictured below. A year ago I updated to 12.0 in order to keep running Mathematica under Mac OS 10.15, Catalina. Now I have to upgrade again in order to keep using the software? I don't mind paying a reasonable price to use Mathematica, but my employer does not cover the cost, so everything is out-of-pocket. Am I the only one who sees this as unreasonable? Am I the only one who wonders if it is too much to expect a company would take better care of their user-base?

My understanding was that Wolfram knew versions prior to 12.0 would be incompatible with OS 10.15 and knew this for a long time, yet the only solution they offered was "you need to upgrade." I would be much more agreeable to upgrading for continued functioning under OS 11 had we not gone through the same situation less than a year ago.

[image: Wolfram email]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Comment: LOL, edited to add a third question.

Comment: As a reminder, this is a Q&A site about how to use Mathematica only.  Questions about company policies are off topic.

Comment: how come I never got this email.

Comment: I think its a reasonable question, these things can't be answered elsewhere.