# Does Mathematica 12.0 work on Mac OS 11 (Big Sur)?

Tags: mac-os-x, version-12

Last month [I shared an email that Wolfram sent regarding incompatibility of Mathematica 12.0 with Mac OS 11](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231553/mathematica-12-not-compatible-with-mac-os-11-big-sur-just-updated-to-12-for-o) (Big Sur). Well, I just upgraded to Big Sur and decided to fire up Mathematica 12.0, to see if it would run, and it did. I tried some basic commands, and they executed. While I would say, this is good news on one level, am I alone in viewing the false "you must upgrade" emails as offensive?

**My question is:** Is Mathematica 12.0 supported on Big Sur? Are there any features that do not work correctly, and if yes, which ones?

Comment: Ask them what specifically is broken and let us know. I would also rephrase the question to ask that to avoid closing it. "Am I alone in viewing the false "you must upgrade" emails as offensive?" is not a practical, answerable question, therefore off-topic. In its current form, it will get closed.

Comment: Related [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2112731) on Wolfram Community.

Comment: Voting to close. I will retract the vote, or vote to re-open, if it is rephrased. Asking what, if anything, is broken would be a very useful question.

Comment: Wolfram referred me to this: https://support.wolfram.com/51740

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and edit the question. I hope you don't mind. This is an important question to ask.

Comment: These edits are fine with me. I found the Wolfram Support article vague and unhelpful. Likewise, interaction with their rep.

Comment: I would also upgrade the question to, is MMA going to run on Rosetta 2 correctly on Big Sur?

Comment: In one of his "CEOing" events on Twitch, I think it was, Stephen Wolfram mentioned that Mathematica 12.2 would be required to run under macOS Big Sur, owing to the OS's new hooks.